# RaspberryPi + PIL + Luma on SSD1351 Adafruit OLED text color and line spacing

Tags: text, colors, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I am new to Python and the RaspberryPi (coming from Arduino).
At the moment I would like to assign the color to a text parsed from a website and I started by modifying one of the examples from the luma library (terminal).
So far I can parse the text and print the OLED screen, but I cannot figure out where to pass the 'fill' value to color the text (ie blue o rgb o any color)
I would also be able to control the line spacing, but I guess I will take one challenge at the time :)

Thanks for your help!

```
import time
from demo_opts import get_device
from luma.core.virtual import terminal
from PIL import ImageFont 
import requests

r =requests.get('https://api.thingspeak.com/someapi)
def make_font(name, size):
font_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fonts', name))
return ImageFont.truetype(font_path, size)

def main():
while True:
    #this one assigns the character and font size
    for fontname, size in [("Volter__28Goldfish_29.ttf", 24), ("miscfs_.ttf", 24)]:
        font = make_font(fontname, size) if fontname else None
        term = terminal(device, font)

        term.println(r.text)
        time.sleep(4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    device = get_device()
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised it... The code is using Terminal from [luma.core](https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.core/blob/master/luma/core/virtual.py?utf8=%E2%9C%93) and the color needs to be passed after terminal is invoked, in this case it's:

```
term = terminal(device, font, color="red")
```